# How to bind FontSize of Label inside a ListView

Tags: xaml, listview, binding, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms

I have a `ListView` whose `ItemSource` is binded to `ArticleList`. I need to Bind the `FontSize` of the `Label` inside it to `MyFontSize` which is **NOT** inside `ArticleList`. Its just another property in my view model, just like `ArticleList`

**XAML code:**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ArticleList}"
          x:Name="ArticleListView" HasUnevenRows="True"
  SeparatorVisibility="None">

  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <ViewCell.View>
          <ContentView>
            <StackLayout Padding="10,0,20,10">

              <Image Source="{Binding _Image}"/>

              <Label Text="{Binding _Description}"
                     FontSize="{Binding MyFontSize}"/>

            </StackLayout>
          </ContentView>
        </ViewCell.View>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to 'target' the element which holds the correct datacontext for your ViewModel. I would guess you hooked it up to your page? Anyhow, the syntax is as follows - with elementname the element with the correct datacontext.

```
{Binding DataContext.MyFontSize, ElementName=LayoutRoot}
```

Great catch by Dushyant Bangal, seems in Xamarin you need to use the Source property for the binding to work :)

```
FontSize="{Binding BindingContext.MyFontSize, Source={Reference LayoutRoot}}"
```

Comment: `ElementName` is not available in Xamarin.Forms. Sorry I didnt specify Xamarin.Forms.But you did point me in right direction.
 The following worked for me:
`FontSize="{Binding BindingContext.MyFontSize, Source={Reference LayoutRoot}}"`

Comment: Combine your answer with mine, will select it as Answer

Comment: Ha, well the 'differences' of Xamarin ;)

Comment: I'm fed up with these small differences. But then again, `Source` and `Reference` make much more sense than `ElementName` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
FontSize="{Binding ElementName=ArticleListView, Path=DataContext.MyFontSize}"
```